# Arduino Serial Port. COM1 does not exist

Tags: arduino-uno

Hello everyone I'am new to this site so please bear with me.

I have an **`Arduino Uno`** that I'm using in my simple project using `VS 2008`. I got this error says `The Port COM1 does not exist`. The flow of my project is after inserting a `coin` into the `coin slot` the arduino will pass the data into my project and it will display into a Label or Textbox the value of the inserted coin.

[image]

Comment: This error is not on Arduino side but on the PC side (.NET code or configuration), hence off-topic here. Voting to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is on another COM port. When I checked my IDE (from Arduino) the Arduino was found at COM3.

You probably have to iterate through the (PC) COM ports to find out where the Arduino is connected to.

Comment: Thakns. I inspect my PC Manager and I don't an arduino driver

Answer (score 2):

Never used Visual Basic but:

- There is no such thing as Serial1 on Arduino Uno. There is only Serial. (Serial1, 2, 3 are available on ArduinoMega) Reference: [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial)
- For COM port you should check your device manager. Often it appears at COM3 so probably you should check this issue.

Just for curiosity: Why VB? Is it only your choice or it use less ram or memory, works faster or anything?

Comment: The Serial1 is from the design built-in in `VS 2008 or 10`. `Just for curiosity: Why VB?` A: don't know how to use another language yet

Comment: Can you program an Arduino?  If so you know the basics of C C++ and C#(.Net).  Switch from VB to C#, its better, trust me, and won't take much learning.